# I want to find sum total of the count of hospitals, I have written following query, Its showing error: Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql, database, count, subquery, data-analysis

#Total No of hospitals from each state#
select sum(num_of_hosp)
from
(select count(distinct hospital) as num_of_hosp
from project.dataset
where score != 'not available'
group by state
order by num_of_hosp DESC)

I have tried above mention query and could not find the required answer. I want to find sum of the count of hospitals from each state

Comment: The error message could not be clear: You need to provide an alias for your subquery. I'm very skeptical whether your query is correct at all beside this issue. If you want to get help, you should please read and follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by the error, you need an *alias* for your derived table. The sub-query in parenthesis after your first *from* creates what is known as a derived table and you must provide an alias:

```
select sum(num_of_hosp) 
from (
  select count(distinct hospital) as num_of_hosp 
  from project.dataset 
  where score != 'not available' 
  group by state
)MyAlias;
```

Note, ordering the rows in your derived table is redundant here too.